# vim NERDTree | Auto fresh the directory pane

Tags: vim, git, vi

How can you auto refresh the directory panes automatically in **vim NERDTree**? I know you can press R to refresh manually but I want to have it refresh automatically. This is particularly helpful when checking out between different git branches.

Comment: Refreshing “automatically” could mean when the file system fires a change event, or every X seconds, or whenever you re-focus Vim after having used a different application to edit files. Vim doesn’t directly support the first two events, but the last one is the autocommand [`FocusGained`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#FocusGained).

Answer (score 4):

For anyone seeing this on 2016, this worked for me:

```
autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * call NERDTreeFocus() | call g:NERDTree.ForCurrentTab().getRoot().refresh() | call g:NERDTree.ForCurrentTab().render() | wincmd w
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

Great [NERD tree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) question. I [googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=vim+nerdtree+auto+update) and found related questions on [monitoring real time changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157914/can-vim-monitor-realtime-changes-to-a-file) and this one on [NerdTree refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584182/how-to-refresh-in-nerdtree-plugin). NERD tree has a built in cache.

UPDATE: following those links and combining the ideas the following put into your .vimrc should refresh every four seconds though an if statement to check for an open NERDTree might be in order too.

```
set autoread
au CursorHold * if exists("t:NerdTreeBufName") | call <SNR>15_refreshRoot() | endif
```

note: still a work in progress. My script number 15 was found using :scriptnames and looking up NERD_Tree.vim. Now to automate that part...

Comment: Depending on how the git checkout is done, the checkout might be used to initiate a refresh.

Comment: Thanks but this did not work. vim says NERDTreeMapRefreshRoot is invalid

Comment: @the-gripmaster `not an editor command`? I fixed it with the `g:` prefix.

Comment: Thanks. No more errors. But I don't see any auto refresh. I will try will a fresh .vimrc and keep you updated.

Comment: @the-gripmaster The .vimrc lines are closer to working. The script number is found using :scriptnames and looking up NERD_Tree.vim.

Comment: To automate calling `refreshRoot()` so it always works, without depending on `:scriptnames` output, I think the best thing would be to edit the NERDTree source to expose that function as a command `:NERDTreeRefreshRoot`. If that command works for you, you could then request that your changes be merged into [the main NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree).